# Computing and using Jacobian for solve_ivp method

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, scipy, ode

I'm trying to compute the Jacobian of a large system of first-order ODE's. I need the Jacobian for use in my solve_ivp code.

Heres how I attempt to compute the jacobian.

```
C1 = sp.symbols('C[0], C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4], C[5], C[6], C[7], C[8], C[9], C[10], C[11], C[12], C[13], C[14], C[15], C[16], C[17]')

X = sp.Matrix([[-1.0*final_kcm[0]*C1[0] - final_kcm[1]*C1[0]*C1[11] - final_kcm[2]*C1[0]*C1[12] - final_kcm[3]*C1[0]*C1[14] - final_kcm[4]*C1[0]*C1[15] - final_kcm[5]*C1[0]*C1[16],
       final_kcm[2]*C1[0]*C1[12] - final_kcm[8]*C1[1]*C1[11] + final_kcm[13]*C1[17]*C1[12],
       final_kcm[1]*C1[0]*C1[11] + final_kcm[6]*C1[12]*C1[11] + final_kcm[7]*C1[11]*C1[13] + final_kcm[8]*C1[11]*C1[1] + final_kcm[9]*C1[11]*C1[9] + final_kcm[10]*C1[11]*C1[10] +  final_kcm[12]*C1[11]*C1[17] + 2*final_kcm[20]*C1[11]*C1[8],
       2*final_kcm[20]*C1[12]*C1[8],
       final_kcm[15]*C1[15]*C1[17],
       final_kcm[7]*C1[11]*C1[13] - final_kcm[18]*C1[5]*C1[11],
       final_kcm[14]*C1[17]*C1[13],
       final_kcm[19]*C1[15]*C1[8],
       final_kcm[17]*C1[15] - 2*final_kcm[19]*C1[12]*C1[8] - final_kcm[20]*C1[12]*C1[8],
       final_kcm[3]*C1[0]*C1[14] - final_kcm[9]*C1[11]*C1[9],
       final_kcm[5]*C1[0]*C1[16] - final_kcm[10]*C1[11]*C1[10],
       final_kcm[0]*C1[0] - final_kcm[1]*C1[0]*C1[11] - final_kcm[6]*C1[12]*C1[11] - final_kcm[7]*C1[11]*C1[13] - final_kcm[8]*C1[11]*C1[1] - final_kcm[9]*C1[11]*C1[9] - final_kcm[10]*C1[11]*C1[10] - final_kcm[11]*C1[11]*C1[10] - final_kcm[12]*C1[11]*C1[17] + final_kcm[14]*C1[17]*C1[14] + final_kcm[15]*C1[15]*C1[17] + final_kcm[16]*C1[13] - final_kcm[18]*C1[5]*C1[11] + final_kcm[19]*C1[12]*C1[8] - 2*final_kcm[20]*C1[12]*C1[8],
       final_kcm[0]*C1[0] - final_kcm[2]*C1[0]*C1[12] - final_kcm[6]*C1[12]*C1[11] + final_kcm[8]*C1[11]*C1[1] - final_kcm[13]*C1[17]*C1[12],
       final_kcm[1]*C1[0]*C1[11] + final_kcm[2]*C1[0]*C1[12] + final_kcm[3]*C1[0]*C1[14] + final_kcm[4]*C1[0]*C1[15] + final_kcm[5]*C1[0]*C1[16] - final_kcm[7]*C1[11]*C1[13] - final_kcm[16]*C1[13],
       -1.0*final_kcm[3]*C1[0]*C1[14] + final_kcm[9]*C1[11]*C1[9] + final_kcm[11]*C1[11]*C1[10] - final_kcm[14]*C1[17]*C1[14],
       -1.0*final_kcm[4]*C1[0]*C1[15] + final_kcm[12]*C1[11]*C1[17] + final_kcm[13]*C1[17]*C1[12] - final_kcm[15]*C1[15]*C1[17] - final_kcm[17]*C1[15] - final_kcm[19]*C1[15]*C1[8],
       -1.0*final_kcm[5]*C1[0]*C1[16] + final_kcm[10]*C1[11]*C1[10] + final_kcm[18]*C1[5]*C1[11],
       final_kcm[4]*C1[0]*C1[15] + final_kcm[6]*C1[12]*C1[11] - final_kcm[11]*C1[11]*C1[10] - final_kcm[12]*C1[11]*C1[17] - final_kcm[13]*C1[17]*C1[12] - final_kcm[14]*C1[17]*C1[13] - final_kcm[15]*C1[15]*C1[17] + final_kcm[16]*C1[13]]])
Y = sp.Matrix(C1)
J =  X.jacobian(Y)
```

This returns a Matrix element like `Matrix([[..]....])`.

How can I transform this into what I need to use it in my `solve_ivp` problem?

Here's my code for my `solve_ivp`  problem.

```
Temperature = 500.0

Temp_K = Temperature + 273.15
r = 8.314459848 #J/K*mol
R = r/1000.0 #kJ/K*mol

Ea = [342,7,42,45,34,48,13,12,4,6,15,0,56,31,30,61,84,90,70,20,70]

k_0 =[5.9 * (10**15), 1.3 * (10**13), 1.0 * (10**12), 5.0 * (10**11), 1.2 * (10**13), 2.0 * (10**11), 1.0 * (10**13), 1.0 * (10**13), 1.7 * (10**13), 1.2 * (10**13), 1.7 * (10**13), 9.1 * (10**10), 1.2 * (10**14), 5.0 * (10**11), 2.0 * (10**10), 3.0 * (10**11), 2.1 * (10**14), 5.0 * (10**14), 2.0 * (10**13), 1.0 * (10**14), 1.6 * (10**14)]



fk1 = [mp.exp((-1.0 * x)/(R*Temp_K)) for x in Ea]
final_k = [fk1*k_0 for fk1,k_0 in zip(fk1,k_0)]
final_kcm = [mpf(x) for x in final_k]

def rhs(t, C):
return[(-1.0*final_kcm[0]*C[0]) - final_kcm[1]*C[0]*C[11] - final_kcm[2]*C[0]*C[12] - final_kcm[3]*C[0]*C[14] - final_kcm[4]*C[0]*C[15] - final_kcm[5]*C[0]*C[16],
       final_kcm[2]*C[0]*C[12] - final_kcm[8]*C[1]*C[11] + final_kcm[13]*C[17]*C[12],
       final_kcm[1]*C[0]*C[11] + final_kcm[6]*C[12]*C[11] + final_kcm[7]*C[11]*C[13] + final_kcm[8]*C[11]*C[1] + final_kcm[9]*C[11]*C[9] + final_kcm[10]*C[11]*C[10] +  final_kcm[12]*C[11]*C[17] + 2*final_kcm[20]*C[11]*C[8],
       2*final_kcm[20]*C[12]*C[8],
       final_kcm[15]*C[15]*C[17],
       final_kcm[7]*C[11]*C[13] - final_kcm[18]*C[5]*C[11],
       final_kcm[14]*C[17]*C[13],
       final_kcm[19]*C[15]*C[8],
       final_kcm[17]*C[15] - 2*final_kcm[19]*C[12]*C[8] - final_kcm[20]*C[12]*C[8],
       final_kcm[3]*C[0]*C[14] - final_kcm[9]*C[11]*C[9],
       final_kcm[5]*C[0]*C[16] - final_kcm[10]*C[11]*C[10],
       final_kcm[0]*C[0] - final_kcm[1]*C[0]*C[11] - final_kcm[6]*C[12]*C[11] - final_kcm[7]*C[11]*C[13] - final_kcm[8]*C[11]*C[1] - final_kcm[9]*C[11]*C[9] - final_kcm[10]*C[11]*C[10] - final_kcm[11]*C[11]*C[10] - final_kcm[12]*C[11]*C[17] + final_kcm[14]*C[17]*C[14] + final_kcm[15]*C[15]*C[17] + final_kcm[16]*C[13] - final_kcm[18]*C[5]*C[11] + final_kcm[19]*C[12]*C[8] - 2*final_kcm[20]*C[12]*C[8],
       final_kcm[0]*C[0] - final_kcm[2]*C[0]*C[12] - final_kcm[6]*C[12]*C[11] + final_kcm[8]*C[11]*C[1] - final_kcm[13]*C[17]*C[12],
       final_kcm[1]*C[0]*C[11] + final_kcm[2]*C[0]*C[12] + final_kcm[3]*C[0]*C[14] + final_kcm[4]*C[0]*C[15] + final_kcm[5]*C[0]*C[16] - final_kcm[7]*C[11]*C[13] - final_kcm[16]*C[13],
       (-1.0*final_kcm[3]*C[0]*C[14]) + final_kcm[9]*C[11]*C[9] + final_kcm[11]*C[11]*C[10] - final_kcm[14]*C[17]*C[14],
       (-1.0*final_kcm[4]*C[0]*C[15]) + final_kcm[12]*C[11]*C[17] + final_kcm[13]*C[17]*C[12] - final_kcm[15]*C[15]*C[17] - final_kcm[17]*C[15] - final_kcm[19]*C[15]*C[8],
       (-1.0*final_kcm[5]*C[0]*C[16]) + final_kcm[10]*C[11]*C[10] + final_kcm[18]*C[5]*C[11],
       final_kcm[4]*C[0]*C[15] + final_kcm[6]*C[12]*C[11] - final_kcm[11]*C[11]*C[10] - final_kcm[12]*C[11]*C[17] - final_kcm[13]*C[17]*C[12] - final_kcm[14]*C[17]*C[13] - final_kcm[15]*C[15]*C[17] + final_kcm[16]*C[13]]
res = solve_ivp(rhs, (0, 3), [0.9999999999929631, 1.8518729652310317e-12, 3.7964305690400015e-12, 4.3194364603720453e-32, 8.840289274135903e-29, 7.58855704948555e-17, 3.747886894978005e-21, 7.443392243056976e-25, 2.713933190549257e-19, 1.3888890038089627e-12, 3.778455148948492e-26, 1.3426298908781515e-12, 4.630881200895968e-13, 2.823935453386071e-12, 9.7200025431433e-13, 3.024125323625077e-19, 1.7428556044758935e-25, 2.314889117721353e-12],  method = 'Radau', jac = J)
```

When I run the code I get the following error as a result.

```
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

What should I do?

Comment: Since you are using symbols anyway, you may want to take a look at [this module of mine](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcode/), which uses symbolic input and can generate an (exact) function for the Jacobian completely automatically using symbolic derivation. Solve IVP is one of the possible back-ends. It may also give you a relevant speed boost.

Comment: Thank you so much, ill get on this and hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I think I solved it using lambdify as follows:

```
C1 = sp.symbols('C[0], C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4], C[5], C[6], C[7], C[8], C[9], C[10], C[11], C[12], C[13], C[14], C[15], C[16], C[17]') 
t1 = sp.symbols('t1') 
ydot = rhs(t1, C1) 
J = sp.Matrix(ydot).jacobian(C1) 
J_func = sp.lambdify((t1,C1), J)
```

J_func can then be used in the solve_ivp method as follows.

```
Y0 = [0.9999999999929631, 1.8518729652310317e-12, 3.7964305690400015e-12, 4.3194364603720453e-32, 8.840289274135903e-29, 7.58855704948555e-17, 3.747886894978005e-21, 7.443392243056976e-25, 2.713933190549257e-19, 1.3888890038089627e-12, 3.778455148948492e-26, 1.3426298908781515e-12, 4.630881200895968e-13, 2.823935453386071e-12, 9.7200025431433e-13, 3.024125323625077e-19, 1.7428556044758935e-25, 2.314889117721353e-12]

res = solve_ivp(rhs, (0, 30), Y0 , method = 'Radau', jac = J_func)
```

**EDIT 2**:
Heres a cleaner code that generates the same thing.

```
def jacob(x, C):
  ydot = rhs(x,C)
  J =  sp.Matrix(ydot).jacobian(C)
  J_func = sp.lambdify((x,C) , J)
  return J_func
```

Comment: You seem to be approximating the Jacobian using finite differences. This is unnecessary as Solve IVP will do this by itself when you do not provide a Jacobian.

Comment: Care to go into more detail on how to calculate the jacobian? I seem to really be stuck and no way of calculating it seems to work. I found this method on math exchange and it worked so i just assumed it to be correct. Edit: Also the jacobian method i use in the question seems to work, but i can't get it to work with solve_ivp. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Your method is not incorrect (AFAICT), just superfluous. The Jacobian is a [clearly defined thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) based on partial derivatives of your right-hand side. You can compute it either on paper (which I do not recommend given the complexity of your problem), symbolically with a computer (which makes sense since you are using symbols anyway), or numerically estimate it using [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). You are doing the latter here, but that’s also what Solve IVP does on its own anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks, i had a small inclination that was the case  when i saw the epsilon value but I wasn't completely sure of anything. When i use 'J =  X.jacobian(Y)' it seems to calculate it symbolically, but i am unable to figure out how to get it to work. I will download you module when i get back to work and post the results if i can get it to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: EDIT: It seems simply lambidifying the Matrix allowed it to be used. I'm still not 100% sure everything is correct but this seems much more plausible. I found a guide on this website [link](https://www.sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial/notebooks/32-chemical-kinetics-symbolic-construction.html)